Laravel Advanced Search in parent table using child table values
so i have a products table and custom_details table in my database.
products can have custom_details and their custom_details can be of type number ,date, or text.
each products can have many custom details so the relationship between them is one to many.
now i want to allow the client to do an advanced search based on the product details available in my database and also perform some sorting based on the custom details
products table
-------------------------------
|id  | name     | description |
| 1  | product1 |             |
| 2  | product2 |             |
| 3  | product3 |             |
| 4  | product4 |             |
-------------------------------

custom_details table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | detailable_id | detailable_type    | data_type | name          | value       |
| 1  | 1             | App\Models\Product | number    | length        | 10          |
| 2  | 1             | App\Models\Product | number    | height        | 19          |
| 3  | 1             | App\Models\Product | text      | factory       | usa         |
| 4  | 1             | App\Models\Product | date      | release_date  | 2024-01-01  |
| 5  | 2             | App\Models\Product | number    | length        | 20          |
| 6  | 2             | App\Models\Product | number    | height        | 50          |
| 7  | 2             | App\Models\Product | text      | factory       | india       |
| 8  | 2             | App\Models\Product | date      | release_date  | 2024-02-01  |
| 9  | 3             | App\Models\Product | number    | length        | 30          |
| 10 | 3             | App\Models\Product | number    | height        | 33          |
| 11 | 3             | App\Models\Product | text      | factory       | philippines |
| 12 | 3             | App\Models\Product | date      | release_date  | 2024-03-01  |
| 13 | 4             | App\Models\Product | number    | length        | 22          |
| 14 | 4             | App\Models\Product | number    | height        | 68          |
| 15 | 4             | App\Models\Product | text      | factory       | hawai       |
| 16 | 4             | App\Models\Product | date      | release_date  | 2024-04-01  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

the endpoint for my advanced search accepts a payload of filters with their corresponding values that will be used to filter the products.
each data_type of my custom_detail have their own implementation of filter. please see below for an example of a filter that i receive from clients
'filters' => [
    [
        'name'   => 'length',
        'type'   => 'number',
        'min'    => 15,
        'max'    => 30,
        'order'  => 'asc',
    ],
    [
        'name'     => 'factory',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'values'   => ['usa', 'hawai'],
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'release_date',
        'type'  => 'date',
        'min'   => '2024-02-01',
        'max'   => '2024-05-06',
    ],
],

this is my implementation of the advanced search using the filters from payload
$query
->select("products.*")
->with(['customDetails', 'category'])
->join('custom_details', function ($query) use ($filters) {
    $query->on('products.id', '=', 'custom_details.detailable_id')
    ->where('custom_details.detailable_type', '=', 'App\Models\Product');
    if (count($filters) > 0) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
                $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                    $query->where('custom_details.name', $filter['name'])
                    ->where('custom_details.type', $filter['type']);
    
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                        switch ($filter['type']) {
                            case 'text':
                                if (isset($filter['values']) && $filter['values']) {
                                    $query->whereIn('custom_details.value', $filter['values']);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'date':
                                if (isset($filter['min']) && $filter['min']) {
                                    $query->whereDate('custom_details.value', '>=' ,$filter['min']);
                                }
        
                                if (isset($filter['max']) && $filter['max']) {
                                    $query->whereDate('custom_details.value', '<=' ,$filter['min']);
                                }
                                
                                break;
                            case 'number':
                                if (isset($filter['min']) && $filter['min']) {
                                    $query->where('custom_details.value', '>=' ,$filter['min']);
                                }
        
                                if (isset($filter['max']) && $filter['max']) {
                                    $query->where('custom_details.value', '<=' ,$filter['max']);
                                }
                                
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                });
                   
            }
        });
    }
});

foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
    if (isset($filter['order'])) {
        $query->orderBy('custom_details.value', $filter['order']);
    }
}

the implementation above gives me the products that passes all the filter criteria but it also gives me the products that passes with atleast one on the filter criteria.
i want to fetch only the products that passes all the filter criteria.
i tried replacing the orWhere with where  but it just gives me no results.
Please help point me to the right direction here. i dont know what mysql function i should use to make this work.

I was able to make it work by using laravel's leftJoinLateral. though im not sure if this the best way. please feel free to provide a better answer.
see below for my implementation of leftJoinLateral.
public function advanceSearch($filters, $totalItems) {
        $baseQuery = $this->model
        ->select($this->model->getTable().".*");
        
        foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
            $baseQuery->leftJoinLateral(
                DB::table('custom_details')
                ->select('value')
                ->where('detailable_type', $this->model::class)
                ->whereColumn('detailable_id', $this->model->getTable().".id")
                ->where('name', $filter['name'])
                ->where('type', $filter['type']),
                $filter['name']."_".$filter['type']
            );
        }

        foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
            switch ($filter['type']) {
                case config('enum.custom_detail_types.text'):
                    if (isset($filter['values']) && $filter['values']) {
                        $baseQuery->whereIn($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", $filter['values']);
                    }
                    break;
                case config('enum.custom_detail_types.date'):
                    if (isset($filter['min']) && $filter['min']) {
                        $baseQuery->whereDate($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", '>=' ,$filter['min']);
                    }

                    if (isset($filter['max']) && $filter['max']) {
                        $baseQuery->whereDate($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", '<=' ,$filter['max']);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                case config('enum.custom_detail_types.number'):
                    if (isset($filter['min']) && $filter['min']) {
                        $baseQuery->where($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", '>=' ,$filter['min']);
                    }

                    if (isset($filter['max']) && $filter['max']) {
                        $baseQuery->where($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", '<=' ,$filter['max']);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                case config('enum.custom_detail_types.boolean'):
                    if (isset($filter['value'])) {
                        $baseQuery->where($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", '1');
                    }
                    
                    break;
                default:
                    if (isset($filter['values']) && count($filter['values']) > 0) {
                        $baseQuery->whereIn($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value" ,$filter['values']);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
            if (isset($filter['order'])) {
                $baseQuery->orderBy($filter['name']."_".$filter['type'].".value", $filter['order']);
            }
        }

        return  $baseQuery->paginate($totalItems ? $totalItems : $this->model->count());
}

